# Excel - regarding highlighting specific cells

Tags: excel

I want to create a montly table in excel. So my issue is this: I have 2 type of clients A and B, that arive in some day of the month and depart another day. What i need to do is to insert in the table the arrival and departure day and also the type of the client and and i want excel to highlight the days of the service i need to provide. For example A client gets service every 2 days.

Is there a good way to do this? I dont have much experience in excel and even though i can to the highligh by hand it gets really boring after 200 clients and also prone to mistakes.

PS uploaded an example of what i want to succeed.   https://ufile.io/j92rp

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alright i got it to work , however i have 2 more questions. What part of the formula i modify to change the frequency. For example my issue is that with the above formula we have a service every 2 days but beetween A (arrival) and the first service there are 2 cells left instead of one ( where one service should take place).

Can you please explain the +4 and +5 in the formula?

Sorry for the long questions but i am new to this and trying to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Please select the whole sheet and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND($B1="A",COLUMN()>MATCH("A",$D1:$AH1,0)+5,COLUMN()<MATCH("D",$D1:$AH1,0)+3,IF(ISODD(MATCH("A",$D1:$AH1,0)),ISODD(COLUMN()),ISEVEN(COLUMN())))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

This is for the example you have provided ("A" - service every two days). A different regimen would require a different rule.

Comment: Thanks. It didnt work very well to be honest but i will try to check your formula and make any appropriate modifications in my file. If i cant make it i will come back to you. Once again thank you very much for your time and help.